# Simplifying my SQL with LEFT JOIN on multiple lines

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, left-join

I am reasonably experienced with MySQL and efficient queries now, but still run into issues...

I have two tables, "invoices" and "salesRecords" the Invoices table contains the basic overview of an invoice, and Sales Records breaks down specific information line by line regarding items purchased.

For simplicity, let's assume the tables look like this:

**Invoices**

```
id    |   repairCharge     |    shippingCharge      |     total
 1    |       28.95        |         0              |     30.45   
 2    |       10.00        |         8.50           |     29.50
```

// Note; the total column includes items shown in sales records

**SalesRecords**

```
invNo  |    itemNo   |  price    |   quantity   | discount  |   
  1    |     123     |  1.50     |      1       |     0     |  
  2    |     121     |  6.50     |      1       |     1.5   |  
  2    |     128     |  5.50     |      1       |     0     |
```

I want to get the total value of items sold, labour charge and shipping charges within a date period, so I need to:

1. Sum all the rows in the Invoices Table
2. `JOIN` (Left?) the SalesRecords Table ON invNo and SUM ((price-discount)*quantity)
3. Use a WHERE clause for date period

I immediately write this SQL:

```
SELECT SUM((sr.price-sr.discount)*sr.quantity) as income,   
   SUM(i.repairCharge) as labour,
   SUM(i.shippingCharge) as carriage 
FROM invoices i 
    LEFT JOIN salesRecords sr ON sr.invNo=i.id
WHERE i.dateTime BETWEEN 1431647999 AND 1434360348`
```

And it is **WRONG**

Because, I get multiple instances of both tables for any invoices which has more than one item line, thus the `repairCharge` and `shippingCharge` values are doubled, or trebled etc depending on how many product lines were purchased on that invoice.

So, I mess around and come up with a solution... but it is pretty **ugly** and presumably inefficient:

```
SELECT SUM(income) as income,
       SUM(labour) as labour,
       SUM(carriage) as carriage 
FROM (SELECT (SELECT SUM((price-discount)*quantity)
              FROM salesRecords
              where invno=i.id
              GROUP BY invNo) as income, 
             SUM(i.repairCharge) as labour,
             SUM(i.shippingCharge) as carriage 
      FROM invoices i 
      WHERE i.dateTime BETWEEN 1434326474 AND 1434361694
      GROUP BY id
     ) totals
```

Can anyone advise the best way to simplify this and make it more efficient?

Comment: Can there be 2 rows in invoices table with same id?

Comment: ID is unique in one table, but not the other?  So some rows are SUM'd multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of legibility, and performance in most other DBMS I would personally just sum the sales records up in a sub-query:

```
SELECT  SUM(COALESCE(sr.Income, 0)) AS Income,
        SUM(i.repairCharge) AS Labour,
        SUM(i.shippingCharge) AS Carriage
FROM    Invoices AS i
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  InvNo, SUM((price-discount)*quantity) AS Income
            FROM    SalesRecords
            GROUP BY InvNo
        ) AS sr
            ON sr.InvNo = i.ID
WHERE   i.dateTime BETWEEN 1434326474 AND 1434361694;
```

MySQL uses intermediate materialisation on subqueries(as far as I am aware), and if it does it may adversely impact the above query, since it will first sum up all records in `SalesRecords` and store the results in a hash table before applying the filter on invoice date, so a version of your effort, but using a JOIN rather than a correlated subquery may perform better:

```
SELECT  SUM(COALESCE(i.Income, 0)) AS Income,
        SUM(i.repairCharge) AS Labour,
        SUM(i.shippingCharge) AS Carriage
FROM    (   SELECT  i.ID,
                    i.repairCharge,
                    i.shippingCharge,
                    SUM((sr.price - sr.discount) * sr.quantity) AS Income
            FROM    Invoices AS i
                    LEFT JOIN SalesRecords AS sr
                        ON sr.InvNo = i.ID
            WHERE   i.dateTime BETWEEN 1434326474 AND 1434361694
            GROUP BY i.ID, i.repairCharge, i.ShippingCharge
        ) AS i;
```

Comment: Corrections: The subquery has no index, not even a hash (until version 5.6).  But it needs none, since the optimizer can start with the materialized subquery, then do Nested Loop Join into the Invoices quite efficiently.  Actually this version _may_ run faster than the original because of the `GROUP BY` shrinking the number of rows to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sum(labour) as labour,
       sum(carriage) as carriage,
       sum(income) as income
from( select sum(i.repairCharge) as labour,
             sum(i.shippingCharge) as carriage,
             coalesce(sum((sr.price - sr.discount) * sr.quantity), 0) as income
      from Invoices i
      left join SalesRecords sr on i.id = sr.invNo
      group by i.id)t
```

Comment: I need to get a single row result.